# useState inside of useEffect not reflecting a change immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I did some research and I've learned that useState is asynchronous, although, I'm still not sure how to fix my particular issue. I need to fetch the data from an api, and the state only updates the second render, plus I need to get only 1 file, so just adding current new state to the previous one is probably not an option.

(the result is that it now says .map is not a function since useState is empty)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/files/public/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setFile(res.data);
    })
}, []);
```

```js
{
  file.map((row, index) => {
    return <li>{index}</li>
  })
}
```

Edit: useState is actually initialized `const [file, setFile] = useState([]);`

Comment: The `useEffect()` will only run after the initial render, you can't have it run before, how are you initialising your `file` state? What is the issue you are facing exactly and why do you need your state set on the first render?

Comment: @Nick parsons. I've added how initilized the state. what I'm trying to get is basically just the .map working properly, and not saying that it's undefined even though I initialized it

Comment: If your state (aka: `file`) starts off as an empty array, you shouldn't be getting an undefined error (I assume you are getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`), unless something else in your code is setting `file` to `undefined`. Are you sure `res.data` is an array, that's the only place I can see the `file` state being set? Can you clarify what error you're getting exactly?

Comment: If you are getting `Uncaught TypeError: file.map is not a function`, then the means `res.data` is most likely not an array, it might help if you share what `res.data` is.

Comment: @Nick Parsons the error is '.map is not a function' even thought file is set to an empty array(you can see it in the edit of the post how exactly it was initialized)
and I'm not getting any error if I'm not using .map(). the result from the api is 1 file, with comments in it, the comments is an array, that's why i need a .map

Comment: Can you share what `res.data` is? Does doing `console.log(Array.isArray(res.data))` say `true`? Are you sure it's an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason you could get this error is if you have initialised the `file` state without providing a value, meaning it has the value of `undefined` (but we would need to see how you're declaring the state to confirm that). As `undefined` is not a Prototype that has a native `map` property (or any properties), you cannot call the `map` property on the initial render.

You should be able to get rid of the error by initialising the state to an empty Array like this:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
```

Setting the initial state means that the first render will treat `file` as an empty Array, so you can call `map` on it and it will simply render nothing (as the Array is empty).

**Sample Final Code:**

```
const MyComponent = () => {
const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/files/public/${id}`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setFile(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {file.map((row, index) => {
        return <li>{index}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Update:**
Another reason could be that the response you are getting from `axios` isn't an Array. In this case, it could be a solution to:

- ensure you've called `res.json()` or `res.text()` on the `axios` response (so you aren't handling a response Object, but are in fact handling the data);
- If the data returned is a stringified Array (such as `'["comment 1","comment 2","etc..."]'`, you need to call `JSON.parse` on it first;
- If the response is an Object, make sure you're pointing to the correct path for the Array, for instance `{ data: { comments: [...] } }` should be accessed with `file.data.comments`

Comment: I already was doing(state initialization) it but it still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: What does the console log print? It's also possible that the second render is the problem if `res.data` updates the state with something other than an Array

Comment: That's probably the problem, It returns a single file, with an array of comments in it, but I guess it's just expecting the array

Comment: Yes, it needs to be an Array.
If it's just a text / JSON file, you may need to parse it from a String into an Array of Strings using `JSON.parse`, for example if the response is something like`'["comment 1","comment 2","etc..."]'` then you need to set the state to `JSON.parse(res.data)`. If you are only receiving a response Object, you will need to call `res.json()` or `res.text()` on the response before handling the data.

Comment: yep, it was the problem, what I did is basically, created a separate useState for comments, and set it to res.data.comments. (pls update your answer so that I could mark it as the correct answer)

Comment: I've always used `fetch`, so that's actually good to know, thanks!

Comment: just for your information,  **axios responses are already served as javascript object**, no need to parse you just need to  get response then  access data. the issue might be that your   file isn't properly formatted. please  Post your  file to have a look.